# SQL Query Update ID with a number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables

- `Student` (studentID, TeacherID)
- `Teacher` (**TeacherID**, Number)
- a temp table `StudentUpdate` (StudentID, **TeacherNumber**)

How do I update the `student.TeacherID` with values from `studentupdate.teacherNumber`?

Please see the difference between `teacherID` and teacher Number. One is the PK and one is just a `nvarchar` column. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As posted there just isn't enough information. This would be a great place for you to start getting the answer you desire. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Each student has just one teacher in your datamodel. And you want to change some students' teachers according to the entries in the temp table? Have you tried anything, yet? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Question looks OK to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using below query. Assuming you have only one teacher for each student

```
update st
set st.TeacherID = t.TeacherID
from Student st 
    inner join StudentUpdate su on su.StudentID = st.StudentID 
    inner join Teacher t on t.Number = su.TeacherNumber
```

Comment: Right on man. no one was able to give me the answer at all on a different thread.

Comment: This is simple and very known. I think people did not answer because they thought you did not ask it clearly.